# Explanation the A* pseudocode found on Wikipedia in a tile grid application

Tags: dictionary, pseudocode, a-star

I was hoping that someone could help me with a bit of clarification on this algorithm. Below is the pseudocode listed for the A* algorithm on Wikipedia. I am very confused as to what "an empty map" and "map with default value of Infinity" are in this case. In the case that the nodes are xy coordinates, and the paths between the nodes are an adjacent xy coordinate (every coordinate being a whole number), then could I receive an explanation on what a map would be in that case? Would it be an empty array of coordinates? How would I represent map with infinity as its value then? What relevance does is have in the code. Sorry if this question isn't very well suited here, I'm just asking for a better explanation from someone who is familiar with the A* algorithm.

```
function A*(start, goal)
// The set of nodes already evaluated
closedSet := {}

// The set of currently discovered nodes that are not evaluated yet.
// Initially, only the start node is known.
openSet := {start}

// For each node, which node it can most efficiently be reached from.
// If a node can be reached from many nodes, cameFrom will eventually contain the
// most efficient previous step.
cameFrom := an empty map

// For each node, the cost of getting from the start node to that node.
gScore := map with default value of Infinity

// The cost of going from start to start is zero.
gScore[start] := 0

// For each node, the total cost of getting from the start node to the goal
// by passing by that node. That value is partly known, partly heuristic.
fScore := map with default value of Infinity

// For the first node, that value is completely heuristic.
fScore[start] := heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

while openSet is not empty
    current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
    if current = goal
        return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

    openSet.Remove(current)
    closedSet.Add(current)

    for each neighbor of current
        if neighbor in closedSet
            continue        // Ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated.

        if neighbor not in openSet  // Discover a new node
            openSet.Add(neighbor)

        // The distance from start to a neighbor
        //the "dist_between" function may vary as per the solution requirements.
        tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
        if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
            continue        // This is not a better path.

        // This path is the best until now. Record it!
        cameFrom[neighbor] := current
        gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
        fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal) 

return failure
```

Here is the reconstruct_path() function:

```
function reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)
total_path := [current]
while current in cameFrom.Keys:
    current := cameFrom[current]
    total_path.append(current)
return total_path
```

Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am very confused as to what "an empty map" and "map with default value of Infinity" are in this case. In the case that the nodes are xy coordinates, and the paths between the nodes are an adjacent xy coordinate (every coordinate being a whole number), then could I receive an explanation on what a map would be in that case? Would it be an empty array of coordinates? How would I represent map with infinity as its value then?

For the word "map" in this context, you should not be thinking of anything like a map in regular english (like an overview of what the area looks like). A map is simply a data structure in which you can store Key-Value pairs, and later on efficiently look up the Value for any given Key. For more info on this, see the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dictionary/info) page.

When they initialize `cameFrom` as an empty map, they simply mean a map that does not yet contain any Key-Value pairs initially. Later on in the code, the line

```
cameFrom[neighbor] := current
```

means that they store `(neighbor, current)` as a Key-Value pair, where `neighbor` is the Key, and `current` is the value. Storing this pairs enables efficient reconstruction of the path later on in the `reconstruct_path()` function.

When they initialize `gScore` as a map with a default value of infinity, this is initially also simply an empty map (containing no pairs). However, with "default value of infinity", they mean that if you ever try to query a value from it with a Key that does not yet exist, it will return infinity as value (the default value).

In the following line of code

```
gScore[start] := 0
```

they add the (Key, Value) pair `(start, 0)` to the map. So, after that, if you were to ask the map what its Value is for Key = `start`, you'd get `0`. If you were to ask the same for any other Key, you'd get the default value of infinity, because at that point in the code it does not contain any other Keys (later on this changes of course, as more pairs are added).

Comment: This answer has been very helpful at clarifying things. I understand your first and last paragraph quite well, but I might need some more clarification on the middle paragraph about Key-Value pairs. So if I understand then in then a key value pair of '(neighbor, current)' is essentially saving the path from your current data node to a neighbor?

Comment: @Morgan In general, keys and values can be anything. In the specific case of `cameFrom` in this algorithm, yes, thats correct. Here we use it for that purpose. Look at the implementation of `reconstruct_path`. We start with `current` being the goal. We use that as key, and the value we get out is the neighbor we were in just before reaching the goal. Then, (in the loop) we use that thing we just got out again, now as key, and again we get the node that came right before the one that game before goal. Keep repeating until we traced back the complete path

Comment: Okay, I'm yet to implement the algorithm but I think I understand it now thanks to your clarification. All I'll have to think about is the implementation now. Thank you very much!